# Explain code: positive integer conversion to other cardinal number, reverse order display

Tags: c

```
// Program to convert a positive interger another base 
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    const char baseDigits[16] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',
                                 '8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' };
    int convertedNumber[64];
    long int numberToConvert;
    int nextDigit, base, index = 0;

    // get the number and the base 


    printf ("Number to be converted?");
    scanf ("%ld", &numberToConvert);
    printf("Base?");
    scanf ("%i",&base);

    // convert to the indicated base

    do {
        convertedNumber[index] = numberToConvert % base;
        ++index;
        numberToConvert = numberToConvert / base;    
    } 
    while (numberToConvert != 0);
    //display the result in the reverse order

    printf(" Converted number = ");

    for (--index;index >= 0; --index) {
        nextDigit = convertedNumber[index];
        printf ("%c", baseDigits[nextDigit]);
    }  

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand this code. How will it be able to show the reverse order? Especially the for statement inside the brackets. Why does `--index` appear twice? What's the meaning it and `index >=0`? What's the use of `nextDigit`?

```
for (--index;index >= 0; --index) {   
    nextDigit = convertedNumber[index];        
    printf ("%c", baseDigits[nextDigit]);
```

Another new question:""
Why we also should output a number at least? and so here with the do loop?""

(Because using scanf to read long integer number of formatted input symbols is %ld. Because even if the user's input is 0 ,we also should output a number 
at least, so here with the do loop)

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Are you asking how a `for` loop works? The first statement executes before the first iteration, so `--index` appears here to decrement it once, since the previous loop left it at a value one higher than needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code basically converts base10 "numberToConvert" to a required base number. I hope you know about this. You can read this for more information.

Now analyse the code.

```
do {
    convertedNumber[index] = numberToConvert % base;
    ++index;
    numberToConvert = numberToConvert / base;    
} 
while (numberToConvert != 0);
```

This code actually do the conversion and stores each digit of new base number as a different number in array.

Example: If input is 146 and you want to convert it to base 13 number, then

```
convertedNumber[0] = 3
convertedNumber[1] = 11
```

At the end of the conversion thread exits from while loop and index value will be 2.

Now it comes to the for loop.

```
for (--index;index >= 0; --index) {
    nextDigit = convertedNumber[index];
    printf ("%c", baseDigits[nextDigit]);
}
```

You need to print value at index 1 and index 0. So index value start with decrementing itself.

Please remember, the first statement in for loop is executed only once. So effectively, there is only one `--index;`per loop.

It finds the character to display for a given digit. Ex: for index[1]=10, it prints 'A' and index[0]=3, it prints '3'. So output is `A3`. This is done to do conversion from base 10 to any base from 2 to 16 (However, that check is not there! You need to add a check for user entered base and make sure it is [2, 16]).

Comment: Thank for your help ,I seem to understand ,the for loop is the key,original ,the first"--index"means"start for"!!,I thought it meant decrease once before!!!So I was in doubt why does --index appear twice?

Comment: @iGeekor: Cool! Make the change I suggested to allow base only in [2,16] range for reliable application.

Comment: You are right,It's a small flaw.I am a c program language beginner，thank you again!You also explain for loop clearly,but my English is not good,so I don't understand yours at the first

Answer (score 1):

For example, consider a number n, that needs to be converted to binary.
Now, if the number n is divided multiple times, by 2, you acquire the binary representation of the number in reverse.For example,
Say n=4, then considering the loop, we find that, the number is stored as 001, in convertedNumber, which is basically the reverse of the binary representation of 4(100).
At the end of the conversion,index is incremented an extra time.For the n=4 case, index=3(2increments + an extra).
So, the for(--index;index>=0;--index) basically states that,
start for loop at index=2(--index(3)=2), loop until index>=0, decrement once after every loop.This would print out the "reverse" of the reverse.(in the n=4 case, 001 is printed as 100, which is binary 4).

Comment: start for loop at index=2(--index(3)=2), loop until index>=0, decrement once after every loop.              I seem to understand this for loop,original first"--index"

Comment: original ,the first"--index"means"start for"!!,I thought it meant decrease once before!!!So I was in doubt why does --index appear twice?

Comment: A suggestion, you could perhaps use a few format specifiers to represent the number as either octal or hexadecimal (%o and %x respectively).So whenever a conversion of a number into octal or hexadecimal is asked for, rather than running the entire code, you could use the format specifier and get the job done quickly.